# Modifying nested document in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document of this structure

```
    {
    "name" : "John David",
    "accounts" : [
            {
                    "zone" : "ABX",
                    "payments" : [
                            {
                                    "units" : 109,
                                    "price" : 965
                            },
                            {
                                    "units" : 144,
                                    "price" : 425
                            }

                    ],
                    "conn_status" : "connected",
            }
    ]}
```

I would like to modify one of "payments" array objects and the following query, replaces the whole set of existing "payments" objects with one (updating) object

```
 db.user.update({"accounts.zone":"ABX","accounts.payments":{"units":109,"price":965}},{$set:{"accounts.$.payments":{units:111,price:443}}})
```

May you please suggest the best way to update a single document, leaving others intact?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this should work :

```
db.user.update({"accounts.zone":"ABX"},{$set:{"accounts.$[].payments.$[doc]":{units:111,price:443}}},{ arrayFilters: [  { "doc": {"units":109,"price":965} } ], multi: true})
```

Hope this help.